# read Office 365 group CustomProperty with Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

We would like to store some extra metadata in the Office365 groups "CustomAttribute..." properties. However most of our processes are based on Graph Api and looks like that these properties are not exposed with a standard call:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/GUID
```

doesn't contain these properties, and

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/GUID?$select=id&$expand=customAttribute1
```

gives `Parsing OData Select and Expand failed: Could not find a property named 'customAttribute1' on type 'microsoft.graph.group'`error.
I can query this property with PowerShell, but I'd rather use Graph. Can somebody please help me how to get this info out of Graph?

Comment: If you want to access Office 365 groups then you need to do the following command, GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$filter=groupTypes/any(c:c+eq+'Unified') and then see if you can able to get the custom attributes. If its not exposed in Graph, then you can use Powershell as alternate.

Comment: Thanks, I can read the groups, that's fine, my question is really how to get these attributes with Graph.

Comment: I think i answered it above... check the API call, if not you need to use Powershell for timebeing and also [raise uservoice/feature request](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests?category_id=359566) so that it can be considered to be implemented..